# Where can I change PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS on a server?

Tags: fastcgi, vps, plesk

Does anyone know where can I increase PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS ? 
I can't find this setting anywhere,

in domain root /etc/ folder has only 3 files: termcap, passwd, group .

I can't access /conf/ folder.

Details:

- VPS

  - Plesk 9.5
  - Linux

Comment: I have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you must have root access to the server.

From what you said, it looks you are logged inside a chroot, that's why you only see etc/ and conf/ dirs.

So, first of all, get root, then you can just edit `/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf` and add the following lines:

```
 FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 1500
 FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 1500
```